# How to compare installed rpm and latest rpm availble on repository?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, centos6

I would like to find difference between installed xyz-1.0.rpm & latest available xyz-1.1.rpm on repository. Also would like to find out any file change happened in new rpm. How can I do that?

please help.
Thanks

Comment: yum-downloadonly https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154 . I.e. download the package, and compare "Changelogs": `/usr/share/doc/[name]/[CHANGES]` Link to all packages / updates http://mirror.centos.org/centos/

Answer (score 3):

1. check the **changelog**

You can check the **changelog** file:

make sure that you have the package `yum-plugin-changelog`

and then you can use this command to print the last (most recent) changelog message for the `xyz` package

```
# yum changelog 1 xyz | less
```

otherwise you can use rpm:

```
# rpm -q --changelog -p xyz-1.0.rpm | less
# rpm -q --changelog -p http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/xyz-1.1.rpm | less
```

---

2. compare the **files list**

to List Files inside the rpm:

Download `xyz-1.1.rpm` and list files in xyz-1.1.txt

```
# rpm -qlp xyz-1.1.rpm > xyz-1.1.txt
```

then list file of the installed package `xyz-1.0.rpm`

```
# rpm -ql xyz > xyz-1.0.txt
```

and finally:

```
# diff xyz-1.0.txt xyz-1.1.txt
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

yum check-update

This command allows you to determine whether any updates are available for your installed packages. yum returns a list of all package updates from all repositories if any are available.

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-yum-useful-commands.html

Comment: how should this show the delta of additional/removed rpms?

Answer (score 0):

You check the latest version of the as mentioned above using `yum check-update` and check the version of the installed rpm: `rpm -qa | grep mypackage`.

Next obtain the a copy of the current rpm and new rpm using `yumdownloader` (you may need to use sudo as some TLS certs may only be accessible to root) e.g:

```
sudo yumdownloader mypackage-current.version
sudo yumdownloader mypackage-latest.version
```

Then install [`pkgdiff`](https://lvc.github.io/pkgdiff/): `sudo yum install pkgdiff` and run it to generate an HTML report on the differences:

```
pkgdiff mypackage-current.version mypackage-latest.version
```